# Visual Studio 2015 Error "Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'Windows.winmd'"

Tags: windows-phone, visual-studio-2015, store

I have a project, on another PCs can build it. 
But my main pc can't.
Errors:
`1: "Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'Windows.winmd'"
2: "Type universe cannot resolve assembly: Windows, Version=255.255.'255.255, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime."`

I tried reinstall the WIN10 SDK and the VS2015, but the errors are same.
It is an Universal Store App.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2015: Type universe cannot resolve assembly: System.Runtime, Version=0.0.0.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36106646/visual-studio-2015-type-universe-cannot-resolve-assembly-system-runtime-versi)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem. I uninstalled all SDK, all VS, all developer tool. After reinstall the VS can build my project.