# Visual Studio 2015 “Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'Windows.winmd'”

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, mvvm-light, windows-10

I'm currently trying to learn UWP and I want to start with the MVVM Light template win10. My problem is the same that this question : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32395660/visual-studio-2015-error-cannot-resolve-assembly-or-windows-metadata-file-wind)

But my many uninstall clean reinstall did not solve my issue =/

Comment: Is the `Windows.winmd` file present in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral` ? The `8.0` may be a different number for Windows 10.

Comment: I don't have the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits` folder, but I solved my issue. Thank you =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... That's awkward... 
I tried to figure this issue out for days, I finally post the question and find,
one minute later, that I only needed to install Windows 10 SDK...